# What are the Rdio Web Service API's rate limits?

Tags: api, rdio

Does [Rdio's Web Service API](http://developer.rdio.com/docs/REST/) have rate limits?  Can't seem to find it in the docs or with a quick search, but I'm getting `403 Developer Over Qps` from scripted calls to the [search endpoint](http://developer.rdio.com/docs/read/rest/Methods#search).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do. When you sign in to your developer account, you can see your rate limits for each app by going to  "My Account".

The default setting is 10 calls per second, and 15,000 per day.[image]

Comment: Any idea what kind of error is raised when you do a request and you are over-quota ?

Comment: Sorry @aurels, I haven't worked with the API for about 18 months.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway. I considered every request failure to be an over quota for now.